# Create distance matrices in R with non-standard methods

Tags: r

I am trying to create a pair of matrices from some experiment data.

The first matrix should be the normalized Levenshtein distance between all pairs of strings in the data, e.g.

|  | neri | pusu | tidi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **neri** | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.25 |
| **pusu** | 0.00 | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| **tidi** | 0.25 | 0.00 | 1.00 |

The second matrix should be the distance between all pairs of meanings in a two-dimensional meaning space, so meanings that differ in one feature have a distance of one and so forth, e.g.

|  | spotted square | spotted triangle | striped triangle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **spotted square** | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| **spotted triangle** | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| **striped triangle** | 2 | 1 | 0 |

Since I am using my own methods of calculating distance I don't think I can use `stringdist::stringdistmatrix` to create these matrices, and since the data isn't numeric I don't think I can use `dist`. I need to just build the matrices manually using my own calculations to fill in the values.

For reference, I'm computing the values as follows (I am using the `levenshtein.distance` function from `vwr` for the words):

```
longer_string = pmax(str_length(word1), str_length(word2))
edit_distance = levenshtein.distance(word1, word2)
normed_distance = (1 / longer_string) * edit_distance
```

And for the meanings (I have the shape and pattern saved in separate columns in my data although I showed them as one unit in the matrix above for ease):

```
meaning_distance <- (shape1 != shape2) + (pattern1 != pattern2)
```

How can I create these matrices using my own calculations? Is there a way of coercing my long data ([head shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjQAH.png)) into the matrix format?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are planning to use the output.

Behind the scenes, the output from "dist" is a triangular array with the distances - e.g. if there's `n` rows, then it has `n*(n-1)/2` entries in a flat 1D array, with the 2nd row using positions n+1 through 2*n-1, and so on.

To get something like that, you simply need to arrange your symmetric calculated distance matrix into such a 1-d numeric vector and then pass that to the function in which you would normally use the output of dist.

Depending on what exactly the next function does with your distance matrix, you might need to add other attributes to it, such as the class (might be as simple as setting the attribute). You can check the attributes of a "distance" object like this:

```r
str(dist(matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=3)))
```

```
 'dist' num [1:3] 0 0 0
 - attr(*, "Size")= int 3
 - attr(*, "Diag")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "method")= chr "euclidean"
 - attr(*, "call")= language dist(x = matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
```